# Unable to put test on Selenium Node

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm using Selenium Grid to do webpage testing.
Selenium Hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub
```

Selenium Node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node  -hub http://192.168.55.209:4444/grid/register browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS
```

And the node was registered at the Hub successfully. 
For the java code I used as follows:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception,MalformedURLException, IOException {
    DesiredCapabilities browser = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    browser.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    try{
    driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.55.209:4444/wd/hub"),browser);
                } finally{
                    if (driver != null) {
                                 driver.quit();
                    }
                }
```

But When the compiler reaches:

```
driver.get(url);
```

It gives me error message as follow, and I didn't find the problem.

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 16:53:24'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:467)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at libraries.Globals.login(Globals.java:242)
    at simple.SimplePolicy.simplePolicy(SimplePolicy.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session ID may not be null
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 16:53:24'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor$CommandInfo.get(HttpCommandExecutor.java:560)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor$CommandInfo.getMethod(HttpCommandExecutor.java:544)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:281)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:446)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: What's up? Closed the browser or unplug wires?

Comment: The node machine would open the browser after I run this test. But it will be closed very shortly. And giving the error message above.

Comment: Does the process remains in memory after that?

Comment: The Browser process on Node Machine? It didn't remains.

Comment: Is Node machine is the same as a server?

Comment: No, they are different machines.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration, you have `browser browserName=firefox`, but you forgot the sign "`-`" before `browser`, so it should be : `-browser browserName=firefox`. This might be a problem; webdriver doesn't give any error, but that specific "`firefox`" cannot be associated with real firefox browser.

Comment: Thanks, But after I correct that command, when it reaches "driver.get(url);", it still gives me the same error message~ And it still says Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session ID may not be null

Comment: Why are you quitting driver right after you are creating him??